# Get all concrete types from ninject

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, ninject

Is there a way with ninject to get the concrete types from a binding? I don't want to instantiate the implementations, just get the type.

I want do to do something like this

```
Type[] concreteTypes = Kernel.GetBindings(typeof(IController)).
    GetImplementingTypes();
```

My `Kernel` is just a `StandardKernel`.

I want to eventually reflect against those types.

Answer (score 4):

The only way is to get all instances using `kernel.GetAll<IController>()`. Ninject does not have a set binding mapping. The implementation is determined when the instances are resolved through injection or get calls. This is because Ninject allows for conditional and implicit bindings.

If you set up an MVC3 application, you do not actually register your controllers as Ninject will determine which controller to load and what to inject into it. It does this by lazily creating an implicit binding.

The closest you can come is to extend `StandardKernel` and access the protected binding set and find all bindings that are not conditional. Once you have all non-conditional bindings, you may be able to pull apart the binding, but I can't remember exactly as they may be hidden behind the `StandardProvider` class.

What are you doing that you need to know the exact binding configuration for a particular interface?

Comment: I realize this is forever ago, but just one place where I need this: I am building a Ninject-based ServiceHost for WCF, to have Ninject build the service instances for me. I need to feed the ServiceHost constructor the type of the concrete service implementation, not the service interface.